# Parallel summation of the array is slower than the sequential one in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing

I write the code for parallel summation of the array with C++ std::thread.
But parallel sum takes 0.6s and sequential sum takes 0.3s.

I don't think that this code does any synchronization on `arr` or `ret`.

Why this situation happening?

My CPU is i7-8700 which has 6 physical cores.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <thread>

// Constants
#define THREADS 4
#define ARR_SIZE 200000000
int ret[THREADS];

// Function for thread.
void parallel_sum(int *arr, int thread_id) {
    int s = ARR_SIZE / THREADS * thread_id, e = ARR_SIZE / THREADS * (thread_id + 1);
    printf("%d, %d\n", s, e);
    for (int i = s; i < e; i++) ret[thread_id] += arr[i];
}

int main() {

    // Variable definitions
    int *arr = new int[ARR_SIZE]; // 1 billion

    time_t t1, t2; // Variable for time consuming checking
    std::thread *threads = new std::thread[THREADS];

    // Initialization
    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) arr[i] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) ret[i] = 0;
    long long int sum = 0;

    // Parallel sum start
    t1 = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) threads[i] = std::thread(parallel_sum, arr, i);
    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) threads[i].join();
    t2 = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) sum += ret[i];
    printf("[%lf] Parallel sum %lld \n", (float)(t2 - t1) / (float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC, sum);
    // Parallel sum end


    sum = 0; // Initialization


    // Sequential sum start
    t1 = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) sum += arr[i];
    t2 = clock();

    printf("[%lf] Sequential sum %lld \n", (float)(t2 - t1) / (float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC, sum);
    // Sequential sum end


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Modern compilers are very good at optimizations, including some vectorization/paralellization. Take a look at the generated code to see what might happen, and what the difference between the two ways might be. Also, how many CPU cores do your system have?

Comment: Are you profiling the printf on parallel_sum?

Comment: Also, read about _false sharing_. This: `ret[thread_id] += arr[i];` likely causes a lot of cache contention. Better to update a local variable inside the loop and then just increment the global counter (possibly atomic).

Comment: Overhead of starting threads, cache use... there are many things that may affect it.

Comment: Thanks!!! @Daniel Langr. Your comment was right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (int i = s; i < e; i++) ret[thread_id] += arr[i];
```

This causes a lot of cache contention since the elements of `ret` array likely share the same cache line. It is generally referred to as **false sharing**.

A simple workaround is to use an auxiliary (thread-)local variable for loop updates and just finally increment the shared counter, such as:

```
int temp = 0;
for (int i = s; i < e; i++) temp += arr[i];
ret[thread_id] += temp;
```

Or, better to use a single global `ret` of type `std::atomic<int>` for multi-threaded sum. Then, you can simply write:

```
int temp = 0;
for (int i = s; i < e; i++) temp += arr[i];
ret += temp;
```

Or, even more-efficiently:

```
ret.fetch_add(temp, std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

Comment: With even the most modest optimizations, `ret[thread_id]` won't actually get written to each iteration in the loop.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It doesn't seem so: https://godbolt.org/z/MFkEbS. Though I would expect the same.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz If the updated variable (array) is not function-local, compilers for some reasons keep the in-loop updates written to memory in each loop (it even prevents vectorization). The same with Clang and Intel: https://godbolt.org/z/DNMgp_. And, the same if `ret` is a parameter of type `int&`. Interesting...

Comment: Quite surprising! There must be some reason for it. I can't imagine they're just not smart enough to perform that optimization. Maybe it doesn't provide any benefit unless there's false sharing. And if the loop only runs a few times and there's no false sharing, it's a pessimization.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Surprising for me as well. Will post a separate question about this issue.

Comment: On a side note: `std::async` also allows you to create threads, however it stores its value in a `std:: future`. That should reduce a lot of the overhead code and prevent false sharing at the same time

Comment: Does `std::memory_order_relaxed` make sense on Intel? I thought they always do the most strict version of atomics as they only have 1 mode in the processors

Comment: @JVApen AFAIK, on Intel architectures, most store/load reorderings are not allowed, but not all of them. Using relaxed memory order might generally (likely not here) avoid generating memory fences, even on Intel.

Answer (score 4):

With compiler optimizations enabled (no point in benchmarking any other way), I get the following results:

> [0.093481] Parallel sum 200000000
>   [0.073333] Sequential sum 200000000

Note that we've logged the *total* CPU consumption in both cases. It's not surprising that the parallel sum uses a bit more total CPU since it has to start threads and aggregate results. The parallel version uses more CPU time because it has more work to do.

You don't log the wall time, but it's likely that because four cores contributed to doing that work, the wall time was probably less in the parallel case. Adding code to log the elapsed wall time revealed that the parallel version used roughly half the wall time of the serial version. At least, on my machine with reasonable compiler optimization settings.

Comment: This obvious reference shows an example on the difference between wall clock time and  cpu time: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock